# How to read values from custom section in web.config

Tags: c#, .net, web-config, .net-2.0

I have added a custom section called `secureAppSettings` to my web.config file:

```xml
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="secureAppSettings" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  </configSections>
  <secureAppSettings>
    <add key="userName" value="username"/>
    <add key="userPassword" value="password"/>
  </secureAppSettings>  
</configuration>
```

`secureAppSettings` is decrypted and has two keys inside it.

Now in my code, I tried to access the keys like this:

```
string userName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.secureAppSettings["userName"];
string userPassword = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.secureAppSettings["userPassword"];
```

But `null` is returning for these fields.

How can I get the field values?

Comment: most useful and always working solution is this one in my opinion:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/28600293/4250041

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You could access them as key/value pairs:

```
NameValueCollection section = (NameValueCollection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("secureAppSettings");
string userName = section["userName"];
string userPassword = section["userPassword"];
```

Comment: it is seperate section than appsettings, this is the new section called "secureAppSettings", how can I get the values in appsettings and also "secureAppSettings" is encrpted now.

Comment: @Manu, sorry I totally misread your question, you are right. I've updated my answer with the correct way of reading those values.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: Is this read-only? Is there a way to set the value?

Comment: @user1177636, yes it's readonly. In a web application it is bad practice to modify web.config as this would result in your application being restarted. Use a database or another persistent storage for this purpose.