# Read value based on key from a Web.config section

Tags: c#, web-config, system.configuration, keyvaluepair

I am trying to create a function that can return the corresponding  value from web.config based on the key provided

For instance, I have these in my Web.config file:

```
<Records>
    <add key="0" value="123cb456" />
    <add key="1" value="hFh343" />
    <add key="2" value="Hdkr625" />
    <add key="3" value="1732HHds" />
    <add key="4" value="optxy33" />
 </Records>
```

I am trying to create a function that can return the corresponding record value based on the key provided .Something like the following

```
 public static string GetSelectedRecordValue(string strkey)
 {
      string strValue;
      foreach (KeyValueConfigurationElement item in Configuration.Settings("Records")
      {
           if (item.Key == strKey)
           {
                strValue = item.Value;
                return strValue;
           }
      }
      return strValue;
 }
```

How to get the contents of my config section into a collection so that I can loop through each item and read correct value record based on a key ?any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why You add this colors in webconfig? You can set these values in **constant** `class` . and you can get easily .

Please refer the below websites

[Link 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173119%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

[Link 2](http://www.dotnetperls.com/const)

But if you want  webconfig,then please see this same discussions

[Reading a key from the Web.Config using ConfigurationManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595288/reading-a-key-from-the-web-config-using-configurationmanager)

[How to read values from custom section in web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329114/how-to-read-a-values-from-new-section-in-web-config)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.web.configuration.webconfigurationmanager.openwebconfiguration(v=vs.90).aspx

or just read the web.config as a normal xml file.