# How to use ConfigurationManager.AppSettings with a custom section?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, appsettings

I need to get "http://example.com" from  using App.config file.

But at the moment I am using:

```cs
string peopleXMLPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["server"];
```

I cannot get the value.

Could you point out what I am doing wrong?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="device" type="System.Configuration.SingleTagSectionHandler" />
    <section name="server" type="System.Configuration.SingleTagSectionHandler" />
  </configSections>
  <device id="1" description="petras room" location="" mall="" />
  <server url="http://example.com" />
</configuration>
```

Comment: http://haacked.com/archive/2007/03/11/custom-configuration-sections-in-3-easy-steps.aspx

Comment: `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyAppSetting"]` only gives you the setting keyed with the name "MyAppSetting" under `<appSettings>` in your configuration file.

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329114/how-to-read-a-values-from-new-section-in-web-config

Comment: `SingleTagSectionHandler` is **deprecated**, and should use `ConfigurationSection` instead ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.iconfigurationsectionhandler?view=netframework-4.8))

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think you need to get the config section, and access that:

```cs
var section = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("server") as NameValueCollection;
var value = section["url"];
```

And you also need to update your config file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="device" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
    <section name="server" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
  </configSections>
  <device>
    <add key="id" value="1" />
    <add key="description" value="petras room" />
    <add key="location" value="" />
    <add key="mall" value="" />
  </device>
  <server>
    <add key="url" value="http://example.com" />
  </server>
</configuration>
```

Edit: [As CodeCaster mentioned in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20195409/718972), `SingleTagSectionHandler` is for internal use only. I think `NameValueSectionHandler` is the preferred way to define config sections.

Comment: using my xml does not work unfortunately,... should i change my xml?

Comment: Yes. You'll need to change `url="http://example.com"` from being an attribute on `server` to being a child `add` tag.

Answer (score 4):

The [`SingleTagSectionHandler` documentation says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.singletagsectionhandler(v=vs.110).aspx):

> This API supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code.

You can retrieve it as a `HashTable` and access its entries using `Configuration.GetSection()`:

```
Hashtable serverTag = (Hashtable)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("server");

string serverUrl = (string)serverTag["url"];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string peopleXMLPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["server"];
```

gets the value from the `appSettings` part of the app.config file but you are storing your value in

```
<server url="http://example.com" />
```

Either put the value in the `appSettings` section as below or retrieve the value from its current location.

You need to add a key value pair to your config's appSettings section. As below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="server" value="http://example.com" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Your reading code is correct but you should probably check for null. If the code fails to read the config value the `string` variable will be null.

Answer (score 0):

You're defining a configuration *section* instead of a *value* in `AppSettings`.  You can simply add your setting to `AppSettings`:

```
<appSettings>
      ... may be some settings here already
      <add key="server" value="http://example.com" />
</appSettings>
```

[Custom config sections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx) are typically used for more complicated configurations (e.g. multiple values per key, non-string values, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the value from the app settings your appsetting element in configuration file must have a key.

define your sever value as mentioned below under **configuration** section:

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
          <add key="server" value="http://example.com" />
    </appSettings>
    ...
    ...
    ...
</configuration>
```

Now execute below code line to get the server url:

```
string peopleXMLPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["server"].ToString();
```