# Load data from App.config and connect to property

Tags: c#, mono

I have defined:

```
public static string Firstname { get; set; }
public static string Surname { get; set; }
public static bool DocBook5 { get; set; }
public static string Language { get; set; }
```

I stored that information in a [App.config](https://github.com/saigkill/PublicanCreators/blob/master/Engine/App.config).

Then i used that to load and connect:

```
Firstname = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["firstname"];
Surname = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["surname"];
DocBook5 = Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["docbook5"]);
Language = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["language"];
```

But if i'm giving out the properties content with Console.WriteLine it looks like the properties are empty.
The full code of the GetConfig class can be shown [there](https://github.com/saigkill/PublicanCreators/blob/master/Engine/GetConfig.cs)

Maybe anyone knows why?

Comment: Can you share you app.config ? And you project is this a console application or web?

Comment: Also can you tell me why you need static properties ?

Comment: You keys are located under <userSetting> node not under AppSetting .And your code is reading from appsetting section . so you are getting blank result

Comment: Your code works fine I just tested it. Check your app.config

Comment: @Yashveer Sing: Thanks for answering. I'm using the static properties for usage inside a static class. But maybe i'm wrong. It's just my first C# app.

Comment: no it will be fine if you are using these values at many place in your application.

Comment: Just now i added the link to the GetConfig class. Also i put all stuff from userSettings to appSettings. I added on the bottom of the class a little checker, which prints the content of the properties. But nothing is set now. Or do i use a false way to check it?

Comment: Any ideas from anyone?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comments you are reading the wrong section not from appsetting . If you need a custom section  in you config please follow this link .http://haacked.com/archive/2007/03/12/custom-configuration-sections-in-3-easy-steps.aspx/ else move them to appsetting section

Answer (score 0):

Look at your App.config.
The data you stored is in **UserSettings** and not in **appSettings**, but you fetched the data from **appSettings**.

Either you put all your data in appSettings, or you define **configSections**, in which you add the name **UserSettings**. (Use '*GetSection*' instead of '
*AppSettings*')

Later, in code, you need to request the specific section, and get the data from there.

Edit: Let me know if you want code example, to match your App.config file

Comment: Hi Ori, can you provide a code example please? I tried it out like so: ConfigurationManager.GetSection("firstname").ToString(); but that doesn't work.

Comment: You want to get the section 'UserSettings' (Working on it)

Comment: Yes. That would be great :-)

Comment: Trying to make this work (I have this in my code, but it's not accessible current - I'm at work) Check out the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20195198/how-to-use-configurationmanager-appsettings-with-a-custom-section