# How to read external config file in C#?

Tags: c#, configuration-files

I have a config file in my C# windows project (e.g. text.Config).In this file I have sections like

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>

  </configSections>
  <FtpSettings>
    <add key="ftpURL" value=""/>
    <add key="ftpUserName" value=""/>
    <add key="ftpPassword" value=""/>
  </FtpSettings>
</configuration>
```

I am using 3.5 framework.

So can you tell me how can I read FtpSettings through this file?

I want all values within this section.

Can anyone give me exact code for this?Without string operations i need value of a particular key.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what have you tried? Show the code you have tried with any errors you may have gotten

Comment: Duplicate. Check this,
[How to read a values from new section in web.config][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329114/how-to-read-a-values-from-new-section-in-web-config

Answer (score 1):

Treat it as an XML file, and then you have many ways to read it.

1. Use [XmlTextReader](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307548)
2. Use [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx)
3. Take a look of others questions, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642293/how-do-i-read-and-parse-an-xml-file-in-c).
4. Many other ways...

Comment: not useful...we have to split string in this examples I need direct value of particular key....

Comment: Yeah how dare you not code it all for him. @ParagVasant ALL of the stuff he gave you here is useful and a valid way of doing exactly what you're asking for.